# Trying to find third lowest salary in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a nested SQL query for finding the third lowest salary but the query doesn't show the correct name of the employee instead it shows gives the highest-paid employee name with the third-lowest salary. This is my query.

```sql
SELECT first_name, MIN(salary)
  FROM employee
 WHERE salary > (SELECT min(salary) 
                 FROM employee
                 WHERE salary > (SELECT min(salary)
                 FROM employee)
                );
```

Comment: What if people have the same salary? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: please provide sample data and expect output. and please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OFFSET/LIMIT` to get the third lowest:

```sql
SELECT first_name, salary
  FROM employee
 WHERE salary
ORDER BY salary
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
```

---

**The reason why your original query didn't work**, is firstly, your select is:

```
SELECT first_name, MIN(salary)
```

which means that there is an implicit "group everything" here, and MySQL interprets the `first_name` as `ANY(first_name)`.

Furthermore, it's extremely inefficient to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname, salary 
FROM employees 
ORDER BY salary ASC 
OFFSET 2 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

select the data and order by salary ascending order. The minimum salary will be the first row, so limit the result to just one row, that is the person with the minimum salary!

```
SELECT first_name, salary
FROM employee
ORDER BY salery 
LIMIT 1;
```